# Puppet remove defined 'message' as ' in output

Tags: automation, output, puppet, server, system-administration

On my puppet client I have the same message twice and I want to only have once.
Example :

```
Info: /Stage[main]/box::Backuppc/Notify[todo]/message: todo...
Info: /Stage[main]/box::Backuppc/Notify[todo]/message: defined 'message' as 'todo...'
```

How can I remove one of them please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current versions of Puppet, the output of

```
notify { "w00t": message => "foo" }
```

looks like

```
Notice: foo
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[w00t]/message: defined 'message' as 'foo'
```

This is only slightly less verbose. There is not really a way to loose/suppress the second message. It has been [discussed briefly](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/puppet-users/547C60B7.9070104%40cern.ch), albeit with no real conclusion.

Personally, I disbelieve that the message can be hidden easily (i.e., without patching Puppet rather severely).